# How can I use my macbook in grayscale?

Tags: macos, display, macbook, color-profiles

Is it possible to make my Macbook monitor display grayscale instead of full color? How can I do that? I looked in the Displays preference plane "color" tab but didn't see anything that looked like it could do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your display to Grayscale in *System Preferences » Universal Access » Display » Use Grayscale*.

[image]

---

Alternatively, the third party application [Nocturne](http://www.blacktree.com/) includes a *monochrome* setting that makes the display greyscale.

[image]

Comment: I cannot provide screenshots, as the effect is applied later, so the screenshots are in color.