# Configure Windows 7 to show all windows in black and white

Tags: windows-7, colors, accessibility

I have difficulty viewing different types of colors.

Many would call it a color impairment, because when I see to many colors my brain gets overloaded.  I would like the following for Windows 7 [How can I use my macbook in grayscale?](https://superuser.com/q/384858)

Is there accessibility setting that can make all windows in Windows 7 black and white?

Answer (score 5):

Try [**NegativeScreen**](http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/):

> NegativeScreen is a Windows application allowing you to invert your screen colors. Apart from accessibility matters, this software is especially useful when you are surfing on the internet in a dark room, and the screen is dazzling you.
>
> NegativeScreen was designed to work without impacting the performances and fluidity of your computer. Unlike the Windows Magnifier, which is also capable of such color inversion, it was specifically designed to be easy and convenient to use.
>
> Different inversion modes are provided, including “smart” modes, allowing black and white inversion, while keeping colors (about) the same.

The different inversion modes listed might be of use to you, including **smart inversion 3** ("overall desaturated, yellows and blues plain bad, actually relaxing and very usable"), **negative sepia**, **negative grayscale**, and especially ***grayscale***.

[Looks like this was developed by [*yaurthek*](https://superuser.com/users/96894/yaurthek), so if it helps you, you know whom to thank.]

Comment: Hmm... It says I must have Windows Aero enabled for this to work properly.  If this works both I am so thankful to both you(Karan) and yaurthek.

Comment: @yaurthek Thank You for such a wonderful application!  Considering you made it, do you know of any way of having the Windows High Contrast theme enabled with Aero?  I have difficulty viewing and would like something with High Contrast and Color Neutral(Black and White).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the start menu and type "high contrast". Click the first link and choose a theme that will suit your needs.

Comment: I am looking for all of Windows to display in black & white.  So far this only appears to effect windows titles.

Comment: You want the images on webpages / pictures in black and white as well?

Comment: Yes the web, and icons, and Microsoft word, etc...

Comment: What monitor do you have?

Comment: I have an HP Elitebook 8460p with Matte display to cut down on glare.  I am very sensitive to bright lights, and colors.

Answer (score 2):

Click Start Button > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Personalization

Scroll down and select one of    the high contrast themes

If the colours are not all to your liking, click Window Colour below the themes list. Here you can adjust the colours of individual screen elements.

Comment: I am looking for all of Windows to display in black & white.  So far this only appears to effect windows titles.

Comment: For example I would like the web to be in black and white.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome or something else for your web browser?

Comment: Well I would like all applications, icons, Microsoft Word, Microsoft powerpoint, etc... to be in black and white.  Just using the web browser as an example.  I currently have firefox, chrome, and internet explorer installed.

Comment: I'm assuming from your comment on ekaj's answer that you would like a black background with white characters. The built in themes don't seem to have a theme that matches that well, but High Contrast Black seems like a good starting point. After selecting that, you will have to use the Window Colour dialog to change the rest of the text, etc. that isn't white to white. The High Contrast White theme is all black and white, but the background is white and I expect that that will be too bright for your needs.

Comment: Note that this won't change everything to black and white. Web pages will still have some colour, especially pictures and video. Word appeared to do a better job.

Comment: I am looking for this setting http://superuser.com/q/384858 but for windows.